# importing DAE files to papervision

Tags: flash, papervision3d

i created a 3d model using sketchup and exported it as a DAE file.

then i try to import the model into papervision, but the model never appear.

when i use the DAE file provided in the examples, it works. only when i tried to create my own models, it doesn't work. does this have anything to do with sketchup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that the problem is that it doesnt appear? the usual problem is scale (it appears huge), and therefore it doesnt appear in the viewframe. try enforcing a size restriction and then realign it to the origin and see if it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, 
Try this out. Import your dae file into BLENDER 3D and export it once again to a dae file. Now this will work. Weird but true. I still have no idea why this works.

Comment: i'm going to try it. Thanks a lot!